# differenced variables in VAR model

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression

everybody.

I'm running a VAR model. I checked out the stationarity with the Dickie Fuller test. Test rejects the Ho of nonstationarity when I differenced the variables twice, so I used twice differenced variables But I don't quite get the interpretation of the resulting parameters, they cannot be the same that in OLS.
I'm under the impression that differentiating the variables makes me lose the information of the original variables. For instance, observing the time series of GDP per capita and expenditure in education, I observed a positive trend, so they would seem positively correlated. But when running the VAR, it would give me a negative coefficient for education, and that does not make much sense.
Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Differencing more than once is rarely warranted in economics. Perhaps you should take a second look at that part.

Comment: Richard Hardy when you say more than one differencing is rarely warranted, does that include a seasonal difference? In other words would you rarely have a seasonal difference and a regular difference?